# Which is the most suitable layout in ExtJs 4 for providing field level security?

Tags: forms, layout, extjs, extjs4, field

Our application provides field level security to client in which a client can configure from backend that a particular field shouldn't get displayed in the form in UI.

We are managing this thing by using hidden property of the fields, setting hidden:true for all such fields in form

But this causes an issue with the layout, as when some of the fields are hidden, then the layout starts looking odd.

In our layout, every row of fields in form is an xtype:'container' and all the fields are present in their respective containers. These all containers join together to be the form items.

**The behavior expected is that when one of the field is set to hidden then the next field moves up to take its place, which doesn't happen in this layout.**

**Could some guide that which is the best layout for providing such a feature?**

Thanks for any help in advance.

PS: Application uses ExtJs 4.1 for UI

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[`Ext.form.FieldContainerView`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.FieldContainer)** for this. I dunno if this will totally solve your issues but this container is definitive the better choice when working with fields.